# type object 'User' has no attribute 'objects django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-jwt

I am trying to get list of user from API with JWT token so I generated the token and with email and pass and trying to make get request with token but I get this error:

```
File "/home/tboss/Desktop/environment/liveimages/backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework_simplejwt/authentication.py", line 111, in get_user
user = User.objects.get(**{api_settings.USER_ID_FIELD: user_id})
rest_framework.request.WrappedAttributeError: type object 'User' has no attribute 'objects'
```

And I have created custom user as:

views.py:

```
from users.models import User
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, permission_classes, authentication_classes  
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny, IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.status import  (
HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,
HTTP_200_OK)
from . import serializers
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication, SessionAuthentication



class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
queryset = User.object.all()
serializer_class = serializers.UserSerializers
```

settings.py:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES':(
    'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
   
),
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES':(
    'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
)
    
}
```

[image: error]

I'm using `User.object` its working fine
but this error comes from JWT.

User models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin
from django.utils import timezone
from django.conf import settings
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from rest_framework.authtoken.models  import Token


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
def _create_user(self, email, password, is_staff, is_superuser, **extra_fields):
    if not email:
        raise ValueError('user must have email address')
    now = timezone.now()
    email = self.normalize_email(email)
    user = self.model(
        email=email,
        is_staff=is_staff,
        is_active=True,
        is_superuser=is_superuser,
        last_login=now,
        date_joined=now,
        **extra_fields
    )
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user
def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
    return self._create_user(email, password, False, False, **extra_fields)

def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
    user=self._create_user(email, password, True, True, **extra_fields)
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
   email = models.EmailField(max_length = 100, unique = True)
   First_Name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, null = True, blank = True)
   Last_Name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, null = True, blank = True)
  is_staff = models.BooleanField(default = False)
  is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default = False)
  is_active = models.BooleanField(default = True)
  last_login = models.DateTimeField(null = True, blank = True)
  date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

  USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
  EMAIL_FIELD = "email"
  REQUIRED_FIELD = []

  object = UserManager()

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return "/users/%i/" % (self.pk)
```

Comment: can you add your settings.py?

Comment: i have added in edits

Comment: It is `.objects` *not* `.object`.

Comment: then i'm getting this error type object 'User' has no attribute 'objects'

Comment: maybe it has something to do with custom user model

Comment: Show us your `User` model.

Comment: user model added in edits

Comment: @afk do you have `rest_framework.authtoken` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: you've misspelled the manager: `object = UserManager()` should be `objects`

Comment: yes its working now

Answer (score 39):

I just hit the same error with Token not User.

You need to add 'rest_framework.authtoken' to your INSTALLED_APPS
And don't forget to manage.py migrate afterward.

That fixed it for me.

Answer (score 3):

I just got the same error and added the following lines into **settings.py** file.

```
SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS': False,
    'BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION': False,
    'UPDATE_LAST_LOGIN': False,
}
```

Alse added the following line into **settings.py** file.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt' #new line
]
```

Also run this command: python manage.py migrate
Now, it's working.

Answer (score 0):

I used this and it worked for me

> python manage.py migrate

Comment: The problem was already addressed in the question's comments and your answer is a bit generic to the problem itself.

Answer (score 0):

check this code

```
    objects = MyUserManager()
```

NO object=...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30617333)